# Collectors mapping() + reducing() - folding stream element having One-To-Many relationship with Java 8

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

The classes that I have the following domain classes:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@ToString
public static class Customer {
    private String id;
    private String name;
}

@Getter
public static class Order {
    private String id;
    private Set<OrderContent> orderContent = new HashSet<>();
    private Customer customer;
    
    public Order(String id, Customer customer) {
        this.id = id;
        this.customer = customer;
    }
    
    public Order addOrderContent(Product product, int amount) {
        orderContent.add(new OrderContent(product, amount));
        return this;
    }
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class Product {
    private String name;
    private BigDecimal price;
}

@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
public static class OrderContent {
    private Product product;
    private Integer quantity;
}
```

So each `Order` is associated with a `Customer` and one-to-many association with `OrderContent`. Each `OrderContent` has properties: *product* and *quantity*.

I would like to return the most valuable *customer*, which is the *customer* that has the highest value of all placed *orders*.

Let's consider the example below:

```
List<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

Customer customer1 = new Customer("1", "Bill");
Customer customer2 = new Customer("2", "John");

Product device1 = new Product("Device 1", new BigDecimal("30.00"));
Product device2 = new Product("Device 2", new BigDecimal("50.00"));
Product device3 = new Product("Device 3", new BigDecimal("110.00"));

orders.add(new Order("1", customer1).addOrderContent(device1 , 1));
orders.add(new Order("2", customer1).addOrderContent(device2 , 1));
orders.add(new Order("3", customer2).addOrderContent(device3, 1));
```

The code below fail to compile. The problem is located inside the collector, because the types of arguments inside `mapping()` does not match. How to implement this logic properly?

*My code:*

```
Customer customer = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer,
        Collectors.mapping((Order order) -> order.getOrderContent().stream()
            .map(orderContent -> orderContent.getProduct().getPrice()
                .multiply(new BigDecimal(orderContent.getQuantity()))),
            Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue))
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey).orElse(null);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were almost there.

The only thing required is to handle properly one-to-many transformation - an *order* into *prices of products* within this *order*.

### Java 9 +

Instead of *collector* `mapping()` to transform `Order` object into a sequence of `OrderContent` objects, you can use *collector* [`flatMapping()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#flatMapping(java.util.function.Function,java.util.stream.Collector)), available since JDK version 9, as the downstream of `groupingBy()`.

And then we can turn each `OrderContent` into `BigDecimal` by multiplying price and amount, and obtain the total amount spent for every `Customer` by using `reducing()` exactly as you did.

```
Customer mostValCust = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer,
        Collectors.flatMapping((Order order) -> order.getOrderContent().stream()
            .map(orderContent -> orderContent.getProduct().getPrice()
                .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(orderContent.getQuantity()))),
        Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .orElse(null);
```

### Java 8

One of the ways to achieve it with Java 8 is to move the logic for accumulating the overall price of each `Order` into the *collector* `reducing()`:

```
Customer mostValCust = orders.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Order::getCustomer,
        Collectors.reducing(
            BigDecimal.ZERO,
            order -> order.getOrderContent().stream()
                .map(orderContent -> orderContent.getProduct().getPrice()
                    .multiply(BigDecimal.valueOf(orderContent.getQuantity())))
                .reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO,BigDecimal::add),
        BigDecimal::add)
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .orElse(null);
```

Comment: thanks very much for the elaborated reply. Exactly what i wanted to achieve.